# How can I extract part of a string via a shell script?

Tags: bash, string

The string is setup like so:

> `href=&quot;`***PART I WANT TO EXTRACT***`&quot;&gt;[link]`

Comment: What shell are you talking about?

Answer (score 2):

use awk

```
$ echo "href=&quot;PART I WANT TO EXTRACT&quot;&gt;[link]" | awk -F"&quot;" '{print $2}'
PART I WANT TO EXTRACT
```

Or using shell itself

```
$ a="href=&quot;PART I WANT TO EXTRACT&quot;&gt;[link]"
$ a=${a//&quot;/}
$ echo ${a/&*/}
PART I WANT TO EXTRACT
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way in Bash:

```
$ string="href=&quot;PART I WANT TO EXTRACT&quot;&gt;[link]"
$ entity="&quot;"
$ string=${string#*${entity}*}
$ string=${string%*${entity}*}
$ echo $string
PART I WANT TO EXTRACT
```

This illustrates two features: Remove matching prefix/suffix pattern and the use of a variable to hold the pattern (you could use a literal instead).

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -o "PART I WANT TO EXTRACT" foo
```

Edit: "PART I WANT TO EXTRACT" can be a regex, i.e.:

```
grep -o http://[a-z/.]* foo
```

Comment: I'm using:
> `grep -o 'http://[a-z/.A-Z0-9]*&quot;&gt;\[link\]'`
but it's giving me:
> `http://img18.imageshack.us/img18/8079/69903601.jpg&quot;&gt;[link]`

I don't want the stuff on the end.

Comment: Well, you could grep to find, and then use grep -o to just get the expression: >grep 'http://[a-z/.A-Z0-9]*&quot;&gt;\[link\]' | grep -o 'http://[a-z/.A-Z0-9]*

Answer (score 0):

```
expr "$string" : 'href="\(.*\)">\[link\]'
```