# How can I extract a portion of a string into a variable in a bash shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, grep

I have an eclipse .classpath file with many lines like

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="/somepath/somelibrary.jar"/>
```

My intention is to write a bash script that will parse each line to test if the library exists. For bonus points, since I know an alternate location on my machine where the library may exist, if not found in the location specified by the classpath file, I'll search the alternate location also and repair the classpath file if possible.

How can I do this?

Seems like [How can I extract part of a string via a shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704234/how-can-i-extract-part-of-a-string-via-a-shell-script) is related, but not sure how to get it into a format like

```
#!/bin/sh
while read f
do
   if [ -f $f ]
   then
      echo "Found: $f"
   else
      echo "Missing: $f"
   fi
done < $1
```

Which I think is my goal.

Comment: can I suggest python, ruby, PHP... ?

Comment: As mentioned by @KarolyHorvath you may be better off with python, ruby, php, other solutions. Bash may not be the most ideal way to parse xml. As `.classpath` happens to be in xml format you can probably make use of `xpath`. You could try to get the list of paths using something as `xpath -q -e classpath/classpathentry[@kind=\"lib\"]/@path <classpath_file> |cut -d '=' -f2|tr -d '"'` or something better

Comment: Truthfully, I'd be happy to do this in any language.  I'm not familiar  (or familiar enough) with any of those mentioned to get this job done. Perhaps you could suggest a solution to the task I'm after ... happy to validate your work :)  I'm currently chasing down the bash version and will update this question with the current state of my script shortly.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -n 's/.*path="\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' file |
while IFS= read -r file
do
   if [ -f "$f" ]
   then
      echo "Found: $f"
   else
      echo "Missing: $f"
   fi
done
```

It won't work for file names containing newlines or double quotes. If you have either of those let us know.

Comment: If it is standard XML, double quotes would be encoded to `&quot;`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `egrep` to get the jar paths out of the classpath file first, then iterate over each of those paths.

```
for f in $(egrep -o '[/a-zA-Z0-9]+\.jar' .classpath); do
   if [ -f $f ]
   then
       echo "Found: $f"
   else
      echo "Missing: $f"
  fi
done
```